# Extending Rstudio docker image

Tags: r, linux, docker, rstudio

I searched for a long time and tried many proposed soultions but did not find a final one for my problem, I hope I can state the question specific enough as I am rather new to the whole docker world.

Ok, here it goes:

- docker containers are run on an offline server (centOS based, doesnt matter I think)

  - we pull docker images locally (on Windows machine, also doesnt matter) and then upload and start them on the offline server
  - for rstudio (rocker) this is sometimes an inconvenience as new packages cannot be downloaded via install.packages('pkgname') but rather have to be downloaded as tar.gz with all dependencies and then uploaded and installed; this works
  - however some packages also need another software to be installed, then our workaround stops working
  - in the specific case I want to install the spacyr pcakage, which downloads and installs miniconda
  - locally it works and my workflow would be (edited)
- `docker pull rocker/rstudio`
- `docker container run -d -e PASSWORD=... -p 28787:8787 rocker/rstudio`
- `docker exec -ti some_name /bin/bash`
- `R`
- `install.packages('spacyr')`
- `library(spacyr)`
- `spacy_install()`
- `q()`
- `exit`
- `docker stop some_name`
- `docker commit some_name rstudio_spacyr`
- -- here I would use `docker save` and then `docker load` on the server --
- `sudo docker run -d -e PASSWORD=...--rm -p -e ROOT=TRUE 38787:8787` rstudio_spacyr

And now here is the problem: spacyr can be loaded via `library(spacyr)`, however `spacy_install()` which worked the previous time now does not anymore with the error message:

```
Finding a python executable with spaCy installed...
Error in set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  : 
  spaCy or language model en is not installed in any of python executables.
```

However, if I go into the Rstudio terminal and type `sudo ls /root/miniconda/bin` I see that everything is there. So my commit seems to have worked, however I don't have root access as the command without sudo results in `ls: cannot access '/root/miniconda/bin': Permission denied`.

Oddly, if I start R from the Rstudio terminal with `sudo R`, then everything works like expected. Unfortunately, we need it work in Rstudio, not solely in R.

What I tried to do (and I know some of these things are scary):

- change permissions for root folder with chmod
- run `system("sudo -i")` from Rstudio -> results in a tty error message
- run `system('su -')` from Rstudio -> results in `su: must be run from a terminal`

Now I really don't know how to exactly proceed with solving this problem and I would appreciate any help I can get.

I suspect that I have to maybe change something in the docker commit step? Or should I really manipulate permissions and users? Maybe I could also look into how exactly miniconda is installed and change it to not be in root? But how?

Thanks a lot for reading and commenting!